# How to allow HTTP traffic and port 27017 on GCE instance with vagrant?

Tags: ruby, vagrant, google-compute-engine

I created a MongoDB GCE instance using Vagrantfile. Then enabled 'Allow HTTP traffic' and added protocol:port tcp:27017 using the console. Everything works fine, but I want to avoid using the console.
Can anyone help me enable 'Allow HTTP traffic' and add 'port tcp:27017' with Vagrantfile?

Here is part of my Vagrantfile:

```rb
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
    config.vm.box = "google/gce"

    config.ssh.forward_agent = true

    config.vm.provider :google do |google, override|
      google.google_project_id = "projectxx"
      google.google_client_email = "xx-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com"
      google.google_json_key_location = "~/gcp_service_keys/xx.json"
      google.name = "namex"
      google.zone = "us-central1-c"      
      google.image_family = 'ubuntu-1804-lts'

      override.ssh.username = "me"
      override.ssh.private_key_path = "~/.ssh/gce"      
    end

    config.vm.provision :shell, path: "install.sh"
end
```

Answer (score 2):

you will have to add a firewall rule and add a "target tag" on it e.g. test-1, then on your vagrant file you will have to  use this line google.tags = ['test-1']

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
    config.vm.box = "google/gce"

```
config.ssh.forward_agent = true

config.vm.provider :google do |google, override|
  google.google_project_id = "projectxx"
  google.google_client_email = "xx-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com"
  google.google_json_key_location = "~/gcp_service_keys/xx.json"
  google.name = "namex"
  google.zone = "us-central1-c"      
  google.image_family = 'ubuntu-1804-lts'
  google.tags = ['test-1'] <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

  override.ssh.username = "me"
  override.ssh.private_key_path = "~/.ssh/gce"      
end

config.vm.provision :shell, path: "install.sh"
```

end

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the vagrant [documentation on forwarded ports](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/networking/forwarded_ports.html#defining-a-forwarded-port)?

Should be something like:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "google/gce"
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 27017
  #... rest of your config
end
```

Comment: Yes, I did try. I think it doesn't work with GCP. It gives me: 

`==> default: Warning! The Google provider doesn't support any of the Vagrant
==> default: high-level network configurations (`config.vm.network`). They
==> default: will be silently ignored.`

Answer (score 0):

Adding network tags does the job.

`google.tags = ['http-server']`